# FIltering result from query

Tags: mysql, sql

This query return users from database MariaDB (MySql).
I need to remove rows from result, where in surname is added "(old)" OR "- R".
How to edit a query?

```
SELECT au.id,
       au.name,
       au.surname
FROM statements s 
JOIN aduser au ON au.id=s.id_usp
WHERE s.id_utv = 10
GROUP BY au.surname
ORDER BY au.surname ASC
```

From this result of query:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | Mike | Argle |
| 221 | Mike | Argle (old) |
| 138 | Lisa | Doe |
| 126 | Lisa | Doe (old) |
| 123 | John | Harris |
| 135 | John | Harris - R |
| 324 | Ann | Perez |
| 329 | Tiffani | Perez |

To this result. Query should return this result:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | Mike | Argle |
| 138 | Lisa | Doe |
| 123 | John | Harris |
| 324 | Ann | Perez |
| 329 | Tiffani | Perez |

Comment: Have you looked at the `like` operator?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `like`, but `like` does not filter rows where are "(old)" OR (- R). Or I just can't do it.

Comment: You should not group by without any aggregation..also the published query shows no attempt to filter - I suggest you add your attempt.

Comment: Sure `like` can do that. Combine with `not`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ROW_NUMBER` window function to select the first value among the `name + ' - R'/' (old)'` doubled values.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  PARTITION BY name, surname REGEXP name+' (- R|(old))'  
                  ORDER BY surname) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT id, name, surname
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iMdaLkipdw5mufzM7W9wHe/2).

---

Your query would get updated as such:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT au.id,
           au.name,
           au.surname,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY au.name, au.surname REGEXP au.name+' (- R|(old))'  
               ORDER BY au.surname) AS rn
    FROM statements s 
    JOIN aduser au ON au.id=s.id_usp
    WHERE s.id_utv = 10
)
SELECT id, name, surname
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY surname ASC
```

Comment: Nice solution with `ROW_NUMBER()`. It works correctly.

Comment: A slight variation in the regex that should work better, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change

WHERE s.id_utv = 10

To

WHERE s.id_utv = 10 AND INSTR(au.surename,'(old') = 0

Comment: I changed in query: `WHERE s.id_utv = 10
  AND INSTR(au.priez, '(old)') = 0
  AND INSTR(au.priez, '- R') = 0`, it works. It filters out the unwanted rows. But it's partial solution, because in result is only one Perez Ann. I need Perez Ann and Perez Tiffani.